# Holomorphic 3-form on Calabi-Yau compactifications

Tags: string-theory, compactification, moduli, calabi-yau

What is the natural scale of the holomorphic 3-form on a Calabi-Yau?

$\Omega=\frac{1}{3!}\Omega_{abc} ~ dz^a\wedge dz^b \wedge dz^c$

$||\Omega||^2 = \frac{1}{3!}\Omega_{abc}\bar{\Omega}^{abc}$

Can $\int \Omega\wedge\bar\Omega = ||\Omega||^2V<<(l_s)^6$?

So, in general, is it $||\Omega||^2\sim 1$ or could we have $||\Omega||^2<<1$ in some compactification? For a specific case, how can we determine $||\Omega||^2$?

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of confusion, I found this reference https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0412250.pdf which has the answer in equation (B.5).

$$ |\Omega|^2 = \Omega_{abc}\bar{\Omega}^{abc} = 48 $$

which comes from the definition of $\Omega_{mnp} = \eta^\dagger_-\gamma_{mnp}\eta_+$ in terms of the spinors and $\gamma$ matrices (3.12), together with the choice of normalisation for the spinors $\eta^{\dagger}_+\eta_+ = \eta^{\dagger}_-\eta_-=1$ (3.14).

These spinors come from the decomposition of the globally defined complex spinor (introduced above (3.3)), whose existence is a requirement of $\mathcal{N}=1$ supersymmetry in $d=4$, responsible for reducing the structure group of the compact space to $SU(3)$.

We were interested in $||\Omega||^2 = \frac{1}{3!}\Omega_{abc}\bar{\Omega}^{abc} = \frac{|\Omega|^2}{6} = 8$, provided we normalise the globally defined spinors as in (3.14). Any other value would mean a different normalisation and one would have to check whether it is consistent with the conventions being used.